# Actionscript block until request completes

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, http, actionscript

I want to make a synchronous request to a server. I want the entire program to stop processing anything until the request is complete and the server has responded; what is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't want the entire program to stop processing anything until the server responds, because this runs the risk that the swf could trigger the "Script has executed for 15 seconds" modal dialog warning to appear in front of your user, at which point you might as well consider your action a lost cause.  This is generally considered to be a "crash" and is "not a good idea."

What is it that you're trying to accomplish that you believe halting all execution (including rendering) will achieve?

If what you *really* want is to just make your application completely non-responsive to user activity during the request, then you might be able to get away with setting mouseChildren = mouseEnabled = false on your application's root movieclip.  If you need to stop the timeline animations, then you'll have to come up with a way to globally find / stop them all yourself.  Obviously, any enter_frame events you're listening for, or timers you're running should stop when you make the request.

You *might* be able to get away with setting the swf's framerate to 0fps in your code (it won't stop the timers, but probably will stop the enter_frames), but if you are writing a 3rd party module then this will definitely make the consumers of your swf very angry.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (and that is, in fact, good thing). Loading is done by player internal code which does not start until user code is finished for frame. That's why you can call Loader.load and add event listener for COMPLETE later.